# How do I add "traditional" Js functions to an Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, frameworks

I am attempting to break into Angular 2. I am coming from raw Js, Html and Css. So this is my first framework.

When I was learning Js one of the first things I learned to do was use the alert(""); because it was simple and easy to do. I am trying to do that in Angular 2 now.

However for the life of me I can't find where to write these "traditional" Js functions.

So, if I wanted to do something like have `alert("Button has been clicked");` run when I click a button, how would I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can always use plain old regular javascript in Angular because Angular is just a javascript framework.

Comment: I have been working through the tutorial on Angular.io. I think I was just psycing myself out. Webstorm didn't suggest anything like it does when you work on a .js file so I thought for sure I was doing something horribly wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/B2viwSKe1K4A61QEan5x?p=preview

If you want to bind a click event to a button, you bind it like this:

```
<button (click)="myAlert()">Click me!</button>
```

I strongly suggest you to read the official documentation on: https://angular.io/

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I don't know why but Webstorm's suggestions aren't showing up for the traditional js stuff so I thought for sure I was doing something wrong